# How to display "Category and Post_tag" component in a CPT Gutenberg edit screen?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, tags, block-editor

I want to use Categories and Tags everywhere in WP (Articles, Pages, Attachments and CPT like for example Jetpack-Portfolio) 
I have been able to show these 2 core taxonomies (category and post_tag) in the classic dasboard for any CPT edit screen I added to Wordpress. 
Despite setting 'show_in_rest' to true, the "Categories and Tags" component is invisible in Guntemberg. 
Note: these 2 taxonomies (category & post_tag) have been added to Pages and Attachments in Guntemberg successfully. 
I don't now how to activate them for CPT. 
 
Can you help me please?

Comment: Please confirm that the categories and tags meta boxes are not simply hidden. Click the kebab/vertical ellipsis button in the upper right of the editor, choose Options, and make sure Tags and Categories are both checked.

Comment: There is no check box "Tags" or "Categories" in the Gutemberg Options Panel.